# TypeError: Can't read property 'map of undefined in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, tabbar, react-props

I am doing react native project. I have array of data and in render method I am trying to looping it, Its like some custom tabbar. But, After loaded, I am trying to switching from one tab to another tab, Its throwing error and crashing like 
[image]

```
TypeError: Can't read property 'map of undefined in React Native .
```

My code is

```
dashboard.js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
    selectedIndex:0,
    tabList:[
      {tabName: ‘Telugu’, tabActiveImage:TeluguActiveImg, tabInactiveImage: TeluguInActiveImg, tabActiveText:'black', tabInactiveText: 'gray'},
      {tabName: ‘Tamil’, tabActiveImage:TeluguActiveImg, tabInactiveImage: TeluguActiveImg, tabActiveText:'black', tabInactiveText: 'gray'},
      {tabName: ’Hindi’, tabActiveImage: HindiActiveImg, tabInactiveImage: HindiInActiveImg, tabActiveText:'black', tabInactiveText: 'gray'},
      {tabName: ‘English’, tabActiveImage: EnglishActiveImg, tabInactiveImage: EnglishInActiveImg, tabActiveText:'black', tabInactiveText: 'gray'},
    ]
}
 }

OnTabItemHandler = (index) => {
    this.setState({selectedIndex:index})
    console.log('selected index is',index)

}

    render(item) {
        const {tabList} = this.state;
        return (
<View>Some static data loading </View>
 <View style = {styles.tabContainer}>
            {
            //loop throught the state
            this.state.tabList.map((item,index)=>{
              return(
                //the style just to make it beautiful and easy to debug
                <View style ={styles.tabInnerContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabIcons}
                  //this onpress to handle of active selected tab
                onPress={()=>this.OnTabItemHandler(index)}
                >
                    <Image
                      //here's the magic show off
                      source={this.state.selectedIndex=index?item.tabActiveImage:item.tabInactiveImage}
                      style={styles.tabItemsImages}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.tabItemTextBlackColor}>{item.tabName}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              )
            })
        }
              </View>
              {this.renderBottomContent(item)}
          </View>


      );
    }
  }
```

> and bottom view is
>   based on tab, I am changing the bottom view

```
 renderBottomContent = (item) => {


    this.state = { dataArray: getListData()}    

    switch(selectedTab) {
      case "Telugu":
        return <View style = {styles.flatListContainer}>  
    //show flat list data
         }
          ItemSeparatorComponent = {() => (
              <View style={{height:15, backgroundColor:'blue'}/>
          )}
      />
    </View >
      case "Tamil":
        return <View style = {styles.bottomStaicScreensForTabs}>
            <Text>
                Tamil feature will come
                </Text>
                </View>
     case "Hindi":
        return <View style = {styles.bottomStaicScreensForTabs}>
            <Text>
                Hindi feature will come
                </Text>
                </View>
    default:
        return <View><Text></Text></View>
    }
  }
```

> And also tab text colour not changing, always coming as black. Can
>   anyone help me, where I am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Try to wrap your whole `render` method with a `View` and remove the `item` parameter from the `render(item)` method

Comment: Still same issue coming

Comment: please add code of `renderBottomContent()` also ! because error occurs on line 190

Comment: Could you try to log the `this.state.tabList` at the beginning of the `render` method to see what's up with it ? And yeah, don't hesitate to put the whole file in there :)

Comment: line number 190 is  this.state.tabList.map((item,index)=>{

Comment: in dashboard.js file ?

Comment: this.state.tabList console 0: {tabName: “Telugu”, tabActiveImage: 3, tabInactiveImage: 1, tabActiveText: "black", tabInactiveText: "gray"}
1: {tabName: “Tamil”, tabActiveImage: 3, tabInactiveImage: 1, tabActiveText: "black", tabInactiveText: "gray"} 2: {tabName: “Hindi”, tabActiveImage: 3, tabInactiveImage: 1, tabActiveText: "black", tabInactiveText: "gray"} 3: {tabName: “English”, tabActiveImage: 3, tabInactiveImage: 1, tabActiveText: "black", tabInactiveText: "gray"}

Comment: @Firu yes, it is.

Comment: @GuillaumeMunsch did you checked my updated code?

Comment: `this.state = { dataArray: getListData()}` what is this? Absolutely avoid to modify state this way! You're overwriting the object without any control. Simply use `this.setState()` every time you need it... in this case `this.setState({dataArray: getListData()})`

Comment: how to handle that dataArray, I am getting from static file called jsonData.js and fetching to dataArray

Comment: @Milore I am very new to react native, Can you guide me how to handle this, Even If I comment bottom method, tabs are not changing active/inactive

Comment: @Milore if I add this.setState({dataArray: getListData()}), Throwing error like maximum update depth exceeded

Comment: Are you calling that renderBottomContent() method for each element? Sorry but I can't help you at the moment, I'll be back in two hours probably. Btw you're code is confusing.. for example, what does `TeluguActiveImg` (or the other tabActiveImage) contain? React Native [Image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) requires a valid url or a valid element.

Comment: I can wait for 2 hours, renderBottomContent()  this method, I have to call for each tab onpress action while I have to show each tab for bottom different data. If active state I can show active Img, else Inactive Img, at a time one tab only active, so, remaining tabs should be like inactive state, thats why I am trying to do.

Comment: And I have local images, not from url images.

Comment: @Milore did you checked my comment?

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper this.state = { dataArray: getListData()}  this is not the correct way. I believe here you want to update the states then use this.setState in this way you are re-initializing states and the old states are got overwritten by dataArray due to which you are getting tabList undefined.

Comment: Even I moved dataArray code to      componentWillMount (){
        this.setState({dataArray: getListData()})
    }
But, now crash stopped, but, its not changing the tabs, index undefined showing in OnTabItemHandler = (index) => {
    this.setState({selectedIndex:index})
    console.log('selected index is',index)

}

Comment: `<Image
                      //here's the magic show off
                      source={(this.state.selectedIndex)===index?item.tabActiveImage:item.tabInactiveImage}
                      style={styles.tabItemsImages}
                    />`
see if this works

Comment: To make order and fix some errors, I've created a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@milore/adequate-mixed-nuts) which tries to replicate your question. I hope this can clarify something. Note that it is not styled as you did, cause you didn't upload style content, and for now images are not dynamic

Comment: @Milore Thanks so much for your suggestions, I will check.

Comment: Let me know, man :)

Comment: Just came out, Will check and update you as soon as possible bro. Really Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Milore Its looks working, But, my text alignment has been changed,Its not coming centre for tab icons. Anyway you can post answer to this question, I can accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better understand the problem I've created a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@milore/adequate-mixed-nuts). I'll post the code here in case it will no longer be available.
Note: it's not styled properly and images are not dynamic as you intend, but it can reproduce the question pretty well.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: 0,
      tabList: [
        {
          tabName: 'Telugu',
          tabActiveImage: '',
          tabInactiveImage: '',
          tabActiveText: 'black',
          tabInactiveText: 'gray',
        },
        {
          tabName: 'Tamil',
          tabActiveImage: '',
          tabInactiveImage: '',
          tabActiveText: 'black',
          tabInactiveText: 'gray',
        },
        {
          tabName: 'Hindi',
          tabActiveImage: '',
          tabInactiveImage: '',
          tabActiveText: 'black',
          tabInactiveText: 'gray',
        },
        {
          tabName: 'English',
          tabActiveImage: '',
          tabInactiveImage: '',
          tabActiveText: 'black',
          tabInactiveText: 'gray',
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  onTabItemHandler = index => {
    this.setState({ selectedIndex: index });
  };

  renderBottomContent = () => {
    const { selectedIndex, tabList } = this.state;
    const itemSelected = tabList[selectedIndex];
    switch (itemSelected.tabName) {
      case 'Telugu':
        return (
          <View style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
            <Text>Telugu feature will come</Text>
          </View>
        );
      case 'Tamil':
        return (
          <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
            <Text>Tamil feature will come</Text>
          </View>
        );
      case 'Hindi':
        return (
          <View style={{backgroundColor: 'cyan'}}>
            <Text>Hindi feature will come</Text>
          </View>
        );
      default:
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>No content</Text>
          </View>
        );
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { tabList, selectedIndex } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Some static data loading </Text>
        <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
          {//loop throught the state
          tabList.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              //the style just to make it beautiful and easy to debug
              <View style={styles.tabInnerContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.tabIcons}
                  //this onpress to handle of active selected tab
                  onPress={() => this.onTabItemHandler(index)}>
                  <Image
                    //here's the magic show off
                    source={
                      selectedIndex === index
                        ? require('./assets/snack-icon.png')
                        : undefined
                    }
                    style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }}
                  />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color:
                        selectedIndex === index
                          ? item.tabActiveText
                          : item.tabInactiveText,
                    }}>
                    {item.tabName}
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            );
          })}
        </View>
        {this.renderBottomContent()}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I'm still here for any clarification or improvement.

**Update**
Adding style like:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  tabContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
});
```

Comment: Its looks fine, But, how you getting same design without using any styles in your code @Milore

Comment: I use style. But you didn't upload it in your post so I've created a StyleSheet more or less equivalent in layout disposition (not the same) based on the image you posted. I'll add it here

Comment: But, Text is not coming like under tab icon, If I applied this style?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Which Text are you referring to?

Comment: Telugu, Tamil, etc text how you showing under tab icon?

Comment: By default the flexDirection of rendering elements is 'column'. So in `<TouchableOpacity />` I have two elements: an image with fixed dimensions and a text which would be displayed immediately after that image. On the countrary if I had to display it on the right side of the image I would have declared `<TouchableOpacity />` with `flexDirection: 'row'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187917/discussion-between-milore-and-anilkumar-ios-developer).